# Continuity along different spaces

Tags: analysis, continuity

1) Say I have a function that is continuous along $\mathbb{R}.$ Would that function be then continuous along $\mathbb{Q}$ ? How about the other way around?

2) If I have two functions that are not equal, would this mean that they differ at at least one point?

*Question 1 and 2 are related to a homework question I have but it's more of for my understanding of the question.

3) say I have two functions, f and g which are both: i) continuous & ii) mapping from the $\mathbb{R}$ -> $\mathbb{R}$ such that f $\neq$ g. How would I begin to prove that there is a q $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$ with g(q) $\neq$ f(q)?

The problem that I am having is that it seems like the fact that f is not equal to g under the reals would already imply that f and g are not equal under the rationals? (since per my possibly-very-mistaken understanding, the rationals are a subset of the reals)

*Note that question 3 is directly that homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Question: A map is continuous if and only if for every open set in the target space, the inverse image is open in the domain. Now consider a map $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and denote by $\tilde{f}$ the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. By continuity of $f$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ for every open $V$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Again by definition of subspace topology $f^{-1}(V) \cap\mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$. But $f^{-1}(V) \cap\mathbb{Q} = \tilde{f}^{-1}(V)$. Since $\tilde{f}^{-1}(V)$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ for all $V$ open in the target space $\mathbb{R}$, $\tilde{f}$ itself is continuous.

Second Question: Yes, think about the contrapositive: if they were equal at all points, then they'd be the same function.

Third Question: Consider the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.